# Can't deploy on Windows Phone 10 emulator - maximum number of developer sideloaded packages

Tags: windows-store-apps

I want to deploy my visual studio project on a windows phone 10 emulator, but I can't! The error message of visual studio is as follows:

```
You have reached the maximum number of developer sideloaded packages allowed on this device. Please uninstall a sideloaded package and try again. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D11)
```

many thanks in advance!

Comment: developers mode on system is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

In [this topic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/aca63449-427c-41ac-82c2-7c6cef56f7a3/unable-to-deploy-winphone-81-app-to-mobile-emulator-100101580?forum=wpdevelop) problem was fixed by selecting x86 as solution platform

Comment: thanks for the hint, but x86 is selected as the solution platform